# Is it necessary to standardise data sets before performing PCA?

Tags: pca, standardization

My data sets are a combination of numerical and categorical data. The categorical data are inputted in a one-hot encoding manner. I would like to ask if it is necessary to standardise the data sets first here before performing PCA? If so, what would be a good way to standardise the data set?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=standardize+%5Bpca%5D

Comment: Some implementations do this any way, at least by default, whereby using a correlation matrix as input is equivalent to standardizing by (value $-$ mean) / SD. But otherwise and in general, mixing units of measurement (including the case where some variables have no units at all) is just absurd: PCA output would  then depend arbitrarily on the scales used,